# How to show the intersection of a line and a hyperplane?

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to prove the following question. I am a bit stuck in it.

[image]

Comment: Start by drawing pictures. Start with $n=2$ and make sure you understand what every bit of information says. Start by understanding that $\mathbf x_1$ and $\mathbf x_2$ are on opposite sides of the hyperplane (line, in this case) $\mathcal H$.

Comment: $n=3$ adds more sense for me, but yes)

Comment: Try to express in mathematical formulas that $x_0$ is on the line passing through $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say $x=tx_1+(1-t)x_2$ (now for me the question how to prove it's a line $\ell$ ($x=tx_1+(1-t)x_2\Leftrightarrow x\in\ell$) passing through $x_1$ and $x_2$ -- let's say it's obvious), so
$n^T(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)=tn^Tx_1+(1-t)n^Tx_2=c$, hence
$t=\frac{c-n^Tx_2}{n^Tx_1-n^Tx_2}$ and we substitute that $t$ back to $x$ 
($1-t=1-\frac{c-n^Tx_2}{n^Tx_1-n^Tx_2}=\frac{n^Tx_1-n^Tx_2-c+n^Tx_2}{n^Tx_1-n^Tx_2}=\frac{n^Tx_1-c}{n^Tx_1-n^Tx_2}$), 
obtaining
$x_0=\frac{1}{n^Tx_1-n^Tx_2}\left(\left(c-n^Tx_2\right)x_1+\left(n^Tx_1-c\right)x_2\right)$ (as intersection of the line and the plane).

Now let's see how a projection is calculated. Let's say $x=u+v$ (for an arbitrary point $x$) such that $n^Tu=c$ and $v||n$ so $u$ is a projection. Let $v=tn$ (that's another $t$), so $(u=x-v=x-tn\hbox{ is on the plane}\Leftrightarrow n^Tu=c\Leftrightarrow)\ \ n^T(x-tn)=c\Leftrightarrow t=\frac{n^Tx-c}{n^Tn}$ -- that's the projection formula for arbitrary $x$, we can substitute $x=tx_1+(1-t)x_2$ and $x_0$ into it...
Let's say $x$ is a point on the line and $x'=x-\frac{n^Tx-c}{n^Tn}n$ is it's projection onto the plane.
Now we can substitute $x=tx_1+(1-t)x_2$ into $x'=x-\frac{n^Tx-c}{n^Tn}n$ and prove that's a line and prove $x_0$ is on it, but we can do easier:
We show that $f(x)=x'(x)+\frac{c}{n^Tn}$ is linear: $f(\alpha x)=\alpha f(x)$, thus we're getting
$x'(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)=f(tx_1)-t\frac{c}{n^Tn}+f((1-t)x)-(1-t)\frac{c}{n^Tn}=$
$tf(x_1)-t\frac{c}{n^Tn}+(1-t)f(x_2)-(1-t)\frac{c}{n^Tn}=tx'(x_1)+(1-t)x'(x_2)$ -- i.e. "the projection of a point on a line, passing through $x_1$ and $x_2$ is point on line, passing through projections of $x_1$ and $x_2$ to that plane" for free.
$f(\alpha x)=\alpha x-\frac{n^T(\alpha x)}{n^Tn}n=
\alpha x-\frac{\alpha(n^Tx)}{n^Tn}n=\alpha\left(x-\frac{n^Tx}{n^Tn}n\right)=\alpha f(x)$.
Now projection of $x_0$ to the plane is on that {projection that line to the plane} too (hmm, why? ) ), but projection of $x_0$ to the plane is $x_0$. QED. )

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. It really helps me a lot. But I have a question, how should I include x0 to both options a and b? I could not do it. 

In option a: Does x stands for x0?
In option b: What is the difference between x and xo at the end?

Comment: See the edits. Fell free to ask. )